# How to search if a particular word exists in keys in yml file using yq

Tags: yq

I just picked up on the yq tool recently and been struggling to find a way to check if a particular word exists in the keys of a yml file.

Say the yml file is as follows,

```
key1:
  value1
key_with_test:
  value2
key3:
  value3
```

In this case, I would like to search if they is a key with the word "test".

I have tried the following commands,

```
yq eval "keys | has("test")"
yq eval "keys | select(. == "*test")"
```

But don't seem to be working as expected. Expected being a bool if exists and maybe if possible how to access that henceforth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yq` uses a different syntax than `jq` to get elements from the array. In the latter you could just do `.arr[]`, but former expects `.arr | .[]`. So putting it together

```bash
yq e 'keys | .[] | select(. == "*test")' yaml
```

Also note that `has` does not support a regex/glob search but only for exact match string.

Note: Since [4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), yq's `eval/e` command is the default command and no longer needs to be specified.